# C# SQLite Bulk parameterized DELETE slow even when using a transaction?

Tags: c#, sqlite

The following code is taking ~2 minutes to delete 30k records which I am sure is too long. Most of the similar questions I have seen on here have been solved by using a `SQLiteTransaction` object, but I am already doing that.

```
private void removeProxiesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (var trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
        {
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand("DELETE FROM Proxy WHERE IP=@ip AND Port=@port", conn, trans))
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in proxiesDataGridView.SelectedRows)
                {
                    var proxy = proxies[row.Index];
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", proxy.IP);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@port", proxy.Port);
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    proxies.Remove(proxy);
                }
            }

            trans.Commit();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the `CREATE` statement for the `Proxy` table.

```
CREATE TABLE "Proxy" 
(
     `ProxyID` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE, 
     `Status` TEXT, 
     `IP` TEXT, 
     `Port` INTEGER, 
     `Country` TEXT, 
     `Speed` INTEGER, 
     `DateAdded` TEXT 
)
```

Comment: You should build DELETE statement that includes information about all rows to delete at once and make sure your deletes does not trigger UI update until all rows are deleted

Comment: @MoreThanChaos Can you post example code as an answer and if it works I can mark it as solved?  I believe I follow what you are saying, like using a StringBuilder to create one giant DELETE statement?  As far as your second statement, yes the 'proxies' object is a BindingList that is a DataSource of a DGV, but even when I comment out proxies.Remove(proxy) it is still very slow.

Comment: Yes it is simple as that, If one giant statement will be too much make it into parts of 500 or 200. Sorry but for now i'm unable to provide you with more complete answer.

Comment: @MoreThanChaos So I just tried your suggestion and it seems to have made a significant difference to just build one large statement.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Building one long SQLite statement with a StringBuilder and only executing the SQLiteCommand object once sped things up significantly.

```
private void removeProxiesButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var conn = new SQLiteConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.dbConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("DELETE FROM Proxy WHERE ProxyID IN (");

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in proxiesDataGridView.SelectedRows)
        {
            var proxy = proxies[row.Index];
            sb.Append(proxy.ProxyID + ",");
        }
        sb[sb.Length - 1] = ')';
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(sb.ToString(), conn))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```